# $R(\sin x,\cos x)\,dx$ this type of integral where $R$ is a rational function can be written into integral of rational function with $t=\tan\frac x2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$R(\sin x,\cos x)\,dx$ this type of integral where $R(u,v)$ is a rational function can be written as an integral of a rational function with $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$.

If it is known that $R(-u,v)=-R(u,v)$ or $R(u,-v)=-R(u,v)$ or $R(-u,-v)=R(u,v)$ then it is suggested to do $t=\cos x$

$t=\sin x$

$t=\tan x$ change.

My question is what are $u$ and $v$ here? Can you please bring specific example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution

Answer (score 2):

If you make a substitution $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$, then you can rewrite $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ in terms of $t$. Indeed, $$ \sin(x) = 2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2}) = \frac{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}) + \cos^2(\frac{x}{2})} = 2\frac{\tan(\frac{x}{2})}{\tan^2(\frac{x}{2}) + 1} = \frac{2t}{t^2+1} $$
Similarly with $\cos(x)$ we get $$ \cos(x) = \cos^2(\frac{x}{2}) - \sin^2(\frac{x}{2}) = \frac{\cos^2(\frac{x}{2}) - \sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}{\cos^2(\frac{x}{2}) + \sin^2(\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{1 - \tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
where both time we used the fact that $\sin^2(\alpha) + \cos^2(\alpha) = 1$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

Moreover, after substitution $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ you get $dt= \frac{1}{2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})}dx = \frac{1}{2}\big(1 +\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})\big)dx $
In other words $\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt = dx$

So integral $$ \int R(\cos(x),\sin(x))dx $$ after substitution $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ becomes $$ \int R\Big(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{t^2+1}\Big)\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt $$

Specific example:
Let's say we want to calculate $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx $. Although it's easier after substitution $t=\cos(x)$, we can try to use our technique of substituting $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$. In our example $R(a,b) = \frac{b}{1+a}$. After substitution we should get $$ \int R\Big(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{t^2+1}\Big)\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt = \int \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt $$ Most of it cancels out and we arrive at $$ \int \frac{2t}{1+t^2}dt = \ln(1+t^2) + C = \ln(1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})) + C$$

Comment: $u$ is $sinx$ and $v$ is $1+cosx$ in example? How you check $R(-u,v)=-R(u,v)$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your recent advice.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is given by *Bioche's rules*: consider the differential form $\omega=R(\sin x,\cos x)\,\mathrm dx$.

- If $\omega$ is invariant by the substitution $x\leftarrow -x$, then set $$u=\cos x,\quad\mathrm d u=-\sin x\,\mathrm dx.$$
- If $\omega$ is invariant by the substitution $x\leftarrow \pi-x$, then set $$u=\sin x,\quad\mathrm d u=\cos x\,\mathrm dx.$$
- If $\omega$ is invariant by the substitution $x\leftarrow \pi+x$, then set $$u=\tan x,\quad\mathrm d u=\dfrac1{\cos^2 x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

If two substitutions make $\omega$ invariant, it is possible to use a trigonometric function of $2x$ as the new variable.

If none works, one indeed sets
$$t=\tan\frac x2, \quad \mathrm dt=\frac12\Bigl(\underbrace{1+\tan ^2\frac x2}_{\displaystyle 1+t^2}\Bigr) \,\mathrm dx.$$